# Time-driven trigger not working in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple code which looks like follows:

```
function setValue() {
  var col = "E";
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = sh.getRange("Sheet2!"+col+"1:"+col).getValues()
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  ct++;
  sh.getRange(col+ct).setValue(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
};
```

What this does is a loop over column *E* to look for the first empty row, and places a random value in it. This is just for testing purposes only and works fine if I trigger the function manually. The function even triggers when I set an *on change* trigger so every time I hit backspace or do something in the Sheet, a new random number appears in Column *E*. This, however, does not work for time-driven triggers. I have tested everything, from setting a trigger every minute through:

*Script editor... --> Resources --> All your triggers --> time-driven --> minutes timer*

and even placing this code:

```
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("setValue")
   .timeBased()
   .after(1 * 60 * 1000)
   .create();
```

which hypothetically should trigger the function a given time after 1 minute has passed. None of these work, and I cannot figure out why. Is there any other way to fire this function every minute? Since the function fires *on change* as well (but this is only a workaround), is there a script which produces and *on change* effect on the sheet which will eventually trigger this function?

Best regards!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the function something other than setValue(), as this is already a method name in the API, that is probably confusing the compiler.

You should be able to use the trigger menu, your code is updating just fine after I just changed the function name.

BTW You want the everyMinutes() method if you want to do it programmatically.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
   .timeBased()
   .everyMinutes(1)
   .create();
```

And if you want this function to fire when there's a change in the spreadsheet, you would just use

```
 function onEdit(e) {
     myfunction();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @zbnrg for your quick response. Unfortunately, placing the everyMinutes() method does not work for me. What this produces is a series of time-driven minute triggers when I look at my Project's Triggers, to be precise, every minute a new trigger is added so basically the trigger is duplicated every minute but still does not set a random number in the first random row in Column _E_. I even tried using _.openByUrl()_ instead of using _getActiveSheet_ but this does not trigger my function at all. Does this have to do with my code structure? Many thanks!!

Comment: Did you change the function name to something else?  I have your exact code up with the function name changed to newValue() and it works.  Also, you don't really need the trigger builder, delete that code and just set it to each minute in the trigger menu, I think you have both happening and it's building a new trigger every minute.

Comment: Yes @zbnrg , I did. I followed your advice and changed the name of the function. I changed it again to _newValue()_ and still nothing happens. Do you have any special settings for the sheet / script ? Do I have to publish something for it to work (this does not make sense to me) ? I even created a new document with merely this script and a blank sheet and still the function does not trigger after a minute.

Comment: Sorry @zbnrg, it works perfectly fine. I feel so stupid instead of setting the trigger in _Current project triggers_ I was placing them in _All your triggers_. Looking at the wrong place. I have one last question which is not really related to this topic, but will this script execute in the background even if the document is closed? Because I would like to do is to place a random number in the first empty row and to the one next to it place a timestamp (I already have the code) which will run overnight. These values will be placed in a chart which will refresh for each new value entered.

Comment: Yes! They will run while not open, but note: it will not be exactly a minute every time.  It will be close, and sometimes Google Services hiccups and just doesn't fire, so be aware of that.